# Can you declare a variable as a structure within the main in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have looked online but I can't find anything...

I know how to make a structure and everything.
I'm just interested to know if you can do something like this.

```
struct Complex{
    float real;
    float imag;
} a, b, c;
```

Now I have a structure for complex numbers a, b and c.

The question is: do I need to place new variables here all the time? Or can I maybe do something like:

```
Complex d;
```

and make `d` a new complex variable for the structure. 
(This doesn't work; I tried it, so I'm wondering if it can be done in some other way.)

Comment: Maybe you want to do `struct Complex d;`. Have a look at `typedef` with structs. (Guessing from memory, it's been a while since I wrote C)

Comment: In C you can use `struct Complex d;` or if you want to use `Complex` without `struct` use `typedef struct { float real; float imag; } Complex;  Complex d;`

Comment: Once you have declared the `struct Complex` type, you an decfine variables of that type, for example: `struct Complex x`.

Comment: Note that if you define the `struct Complex` type inside `main()`, you cannot officially create any functions that work with the type — it is a new type, distinct from any other type `struct Complex` defined anywhere else.  Consequently, it is essentially never sensible to define a structure type at function scope (but there's a 0.01% chance that it is occasionally useful — very seldom, but occasionally).  In practice, you'll often get away with abusing the rules, but don't risk it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, e.g. "do I need to place new variables here all the time." I don't know what you mean by "new" or "here" or "place".  Can you please post a complete piece of code that illustrates what you want to achieve?

Comment: `struct Complex { float real; float imag; } a, b, c;` is equivalent to `struct Complex { float real; float imag; };` `struct Complex a, b, c;` They both declare a complete type `struct Complex` and declare three variables of that type. The type is `struct Complex`, not `Complex`. If you declare the complete type `struct Complex` inside the `main` function (or inside any other block), its scope is limited to that block, so usually the type declaration would be placed outside the functions so the same type can be used by more than one function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does two things:

- It creates a structure type named `struct Complex`
- It creates three variables of that type.

You don't need to both at once, however.  You can declare the struct type:

```
struct Complex{
    float real;
    float imag;
};
```

Then create variables of that type:

```
struct Complex a, b, c, d;
```

Note that the name of the struct is `struct Complex`.  `Complex` would be the name of a different type created with `typedef`.

Comment: In C++, the type name `Complex` would be available — but this question is not about C++.  Nevertheless, this leads to confusion, especially if people compile their C code with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typedef` instead:

```
typedef struct {
    float real;
    float imag;
} Complex;
```

Note that we don't need to write something after `struct` since we use `typedef`
Then if we want to declare a variable of `Complex` type, we can just write like this:

```
Complex a, b, c, d; /* or any other variable*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this answer your question?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct Complex
    {
        float real;
        float imag;
    } a, b, c;
    struct Complex d = (struct Complex) {.real=3.14, .imag=-2.8};
    printf("Value d: {.real = %.2f, .imag = %.2f }\n", d.real, d.imag);
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/aeCMva)

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4380KB
Value d: {.real = 3.14, .imag = -2.80 }
```